# Engraving displayed from two sides

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to engrave an image to the bottom of an object. The problem is that it ends up projecting both on the bottom and the top.

[image: Engraved on top (not wanted)]

[image: Engraved on bottom]

My nodes look like this:[image]

I think the problem is in UV editing. When I look on the object from the bottom and project it from view, the top is also displayed, like so

[image]

I've tried only selecting the bottom of object when projecting, but the result wasn't changed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select everything but the bottom and in the UV Editor, move and scale the UVs in order to place them over a part of your image that has no signs.